# NFSv4 hangs on mount

Tags: centos7, nfs, nfs4

NFS mount commands hangs on client indefinitely after server reboot.

I am running this command : `mount -t nfs -v 10.17.25.27:/DATA/projects/assets-db/log-apache test`

My NFS server is : `10.17.25.27`, the client IP is `10.17.25.152`

I have enabled syslog debug for nfs and I see these errors :

```
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid_confirm auth=UNIX, (client ID 9ee5cc5a6d8c0000)
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid_confirm: -10008
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid auth=UNIX, 'Linux NFSv4.0 10.17.25.152/10.17.25.27 tcp'
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid: 0
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid_confirm auth=UNIX, (client ID 9ee5cc5a6e8c0000)
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid_confirm: -10008
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs_put_client({8})
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS: <-- nfs40_walk_client_list status = -10008
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs4_create_server()
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs4_init_server()
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs4_set_client()
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs_get_client(10.17.25.27,v4)
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: <-- nfs_found_client found nfs_client ffff8801e93a0400 for 10.17.25.27
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: <-- nfs4_set_client() = 0 [new ffff8801e93a0400]
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: <-- nfs4_init_server() = 0
Aug 31 16:26:06 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs4_get_rootfh()
...
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid_confirm auth=UNIX, (client ID 9ee5cc5a6f8c0000)
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid_confirm: -10008
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid auth=UNIX, 'Linux NFSv4.0 10.17.25.152/10.17.25.27 tcp'
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid: 0
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid_confirm auth=UNIX, (client ID 9ee5cc5a708c0000)
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid_confirm: -10008
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs_put_client({9})
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS: <-- nfs40_walk_client_list status = -10008
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: nfs4_get_rootfh: getroot error = 512
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: <-- nfs4_get_rootfh() = -512
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs_free_server()
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs_put_client({8})
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: <-- nfs_free_server()
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: <-- nfs4_create_server() = error -512
...
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid_confirm auth=UNIX, (client ID 9ee5cc5a6f8c0000)
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid_confirm: -10008
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid auth=UNIX, 'Linux NFSv4.0 10.17.25.152/10.17.25.27 tcp'
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid: 0
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid_confirm auth=UNIX, (client ID 9ee5cc5a708c0000)
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid_confirm: -10008
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs_put_client({9})
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS: <-- nfs40_walk_client_list status = -10008
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: nfs4_get_rootfh: getroot error = 512
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: <-- nfs4_get_rootfh() = -512
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs_free_server()
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs_put_client({8})
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: <-- nfs_free_server()
Aug 31 16:26:08 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: <-- nfs4_create_server() = error -512
Aug 31 16:26:09 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid_confirm auth=UNIX, (client ID 9ee5cc5a708c0000)
Aug 31 16:26:09 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid_confirm: -10008
Aug 31 16:26:09 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid auth=UNIX, 'Linux NFSv4.0 10.17.25.152/10.17.25.27 tcp'
Aug 31 16:26:09 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid: 0
Aug 31 16:26:09 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS call  setclientid_confirm auth=UNIX, (client ID 9ee5cc5a718c0000)
Aug 31 16:26:09 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS reply setclientid_confirm: -10008
Aug 31 16:26:09 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: --> nfs_put_client({8})
Aug 31 16:26:09 SEFRAPP05155 kernel: NFS: <-- nfs40_walk_client_list status = -10008
```

I see these kinds of log lines repeated.

When I run `rpcinfo -p  10.17.25.27` on the client, I see :

```
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp    662  status
    100005    1   udp    892  mountd
    100024    1   tcp    662  status
    100005    1   tcp    892  mountd
    100005    2   udp    892  mountd
    100005    2   tcp    892  mountd
    100005    3   udp    892  mountd
    100005    3   tcp    892  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  32768  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  32768  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  32768  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  32768  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  32768  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  32768  nlockmgr
```

Note that mounting with version 3 of NFS works but I need features from  the version 4, so I cannot downgrade to this older version of the protocol.

I am on `CentOS 7.2` with kernel `3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did not find as to why our NFS suddenly went down and after restart, clients were not able to mount any exported filesystem. We tried to restart all the servers, to open all the ports between the machines but nothing did the trick.

However, we were able to make it work again after we upgraded the kernel from version `3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64` to `3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64`